# What is function designator and actual call?

Tags: c, function, arguments, language-lawyer, c99

According to C99 Standard:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

Could anyone explain clearly what is function designator and actual call; and what is difference between them ?

Comment: I think you already know what the call is, but are confused. The function designator is what needs to be explained.

Comment: i know what is the call but i thought that actual call can be different like the difference between actual arguments and formal arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function designator is an expression with function type. That is, when you type `func(a,b);` to call a function, `func` is the function designator.

(Such a function designator when present in an expression normally "decays" into a pointer to function, much like arrays decay into a pointer to the first element.)

The meaning of "sequence point before the actual call" is that all operands must be fully evaluated (executed) before the function is called.
If you have `func(a(), b())`, it is unspecified if `a()` or `b()` is executed first, but you know that both of them are definitely executed before `func` is called.

So if `a()` for example modified a global variable that is also used by `func`, that would be fine because the access to that variable would be sequenced in a well-defined order.

---

EDIT - sources

There's C17 6.5.2.2 *requiring* a function pointer whenever a function is called:

> **Constraints**
> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function returning `void` or returning a complete object type other than an array type.

This is made possible by mandatory "function decay", C17 6.3.2.1/4:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

Comment: Well, Could you please give an function designator evaluation example ?

Comment: @UlaşSezgin It's an operand just like any other, but not a terribly exciting one. You could as well use a function pointer though, in which case it might point at different functions each time.

Comment: @Lundin How to understand that **a function designator when present in an expression normally "decays" into a pointer to function** in the right way? For example, do you mean `std::hex` is decayed to a function pointer in the expression of `std::cout << std::hex`?

Comment: @John This is tagged C and ostream in C++ is a topic of its own, with various operator overloading. But yes, any function when used in an expression decays into a function pointer. I'll update the answer with some quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the function designator is what tells the program *which* function to call. It might be either a function name or an expression resulting in a function pointer.

Edit:

Here is a function pointer example:

```
// Two random functions
int foo(int i);
int bar(int i);

// define a function pointer type
typedef int (* func)(int)

// Array of functions

func a[] = {foo, bar}


// calling bar(123)
// (a[1]) is an expression that evaluates to a pointer to `bar`

(a[1])(123);
```

Comment: if it is just a name what does the c99 mean as ''evaluation of the function designator''

Comment: @UlaşSezgin, because it is not always a name determined at compile time. It might also be an expression that is evaluated at runtime to determine which function to call. I would recommend that you try to learn about function pointers.

Comment: Why would you assume? This is defined in the C standard: “A *function designator* is an expression that has function type…” (C 2018 6.3.2.1 4). A pointer is not a function designator. I would recommend that you try to learn about function designators.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I "assumed" because i didn't have the standard text in front of me. Then I also assumed that since the poster asked for an explanation and obviously had not learned about function pointers yet, a more pragmatic answer would be more apropriate than dry c-standard quotes.

Answer (score 3):

> "*What is a function designator?*"

---

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, 66) or the unary & operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".
>
> 66) Because this conversion does not occur, the operand of the sizeof operator remains a function designator and violates the constraints in 6.5.3.4.
>
> Source: C18, §6.3.2.1/4 - "Lvalues, arrays, and function designators"

---

A function designator is an expression which *identifies* a certain function and that *designates* a function when evaluated.

```
int tip (int);
```

`tip` (the name of the function)  is for example a function designator.

Or for example in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tip (int a) {
    return a;
}

int main (void) {

    int (**foo)(int);

    int (*bar[5])(int);

    bar[0] = &tip;

    foo = &bar;

    printf("%d", (**foo)(4));
}
```

The pointer to pointer to function returning int `foo` - `(**foo)(4)` - is a function designator for the function `tip`.

---

"*What is the function call?*"

The function call is actually just the call to a function, like `tip(4);`.

Comment: could you please give an function designator example ?

Comment: @UlaşSezgin Yes, did it.

Comment: Actually, `(**foo)(4)` is not a pointer to a pointer to a function: It evaluates as follows: `(**foo)(4)` -> `(**&bar)(4)` -> `(*bar)(4)` -> `(*&bar[0])(4)` -> `(bar[0])(4)` -> `(&tip)(4)` and is thus an ordinary function call. But I think you could say that `*bar[0]` is a function designator. You could retain `foo` in your present code by adding `(**foo)(4)` alongside your `tip(4)` example.

Comment: *Actually* what you intended in your example code is probably the line `foo = &bar[0]` -- that way you can say that `foo` is a pointer to a pointer to a function (but I think it's confusingly phrased with the interspersed `(**foo)(4)`). Also note that `&bar` and `&bar[0]` have different types, despite their identical values.